# WordPress wp_nav_menu is breaking my loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

When I try to update an old theme that had been using wp_list_pages to use wp_nav_menu, the loop to show my posts and pages breaks. I have tried different implementations including:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/getting-started-with-wordpress-custom-menus/

http://wpfirstaid.com/2010/07/upgrade-wp_list_pages-to-wp_nav_menu/

And the basic implementation from the WordPress codex.

Making the changes to functions.php has no effect on the loop, but when I add any version of wp_nav_menu into my template, it prevents the loop that calls the post or page from working. My loop is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

If I use query_posts then the content will show, but something about the loop isn't working with wp_nav_menu. What appears is an empty post with the wrong ID (and post_class isn't working right either):

```
<div class="post--42 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry" id="post--42">
        <h2></h2>
```

The code for that is:

```
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Right below the faulty loop. Every post or page displays this particular ID.

Any ideas?

Edit to add:

Right now in the functions.php I have:

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_menu');

function register_custom_menu() {
register_nav_menu('header', 'Header Menu');
}
```

And in my header.php I have:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Header Menu')); ?>
```

And the menu I created is selected in the GUI. The menu displays perfectly but the content on the page is gone.

Answer (score 0):

With the info you provided i think you need to add endwhile as show below. Let me know if this is the case or not :)

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

and ends here:

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Be sure to include the call for the header Template at the top of your Theme's Templates. If you are using The Loop inside your own design (and your own design is not a template), set WP_USE_THEMES to false.

```
<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); get_header(); ?>
```

**Referance Link** -  http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Sorry, I should have put that in too. At the end of my loop there is: <?php endwhile; else: ?>

  <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

<?php endif; ?> and I have tried placing the <?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); get_header(); ?> but it didn't have an effect.

Comment: I should add that the loop works completely as expected until I add <?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?> into the template. (The implementation does not seem to matter, like if I put the arguments directly into the function nothing changes.) The menu itself works perfectly, it's just the post or page content that disappears because the loop is broken.

Comment: @Kelly very thx for the quick reply..ok..i m assuming you r using the latest wordpress version....and you have created the menu frm the backend and you changed the "Theme Locations" to your selected and then using <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Project Nav' )); ?>

Comment: Yes, have tried different ways of implementing but all have created the menu successfully and broken the loop for the page content. Will add to the question...

Comment: And yes the WP version is 3.4.1

Comment: @Kelly very sorry bro for the delay(stuck with some work)...let me know if u have to retrieve all data from pages assigned to menu ..is this the case?????

Comment: no worries, thanks for helping! I'm not sure what you mean by your question, sorry? I did put debug mode on and I see three warnings with wp_nav_menu that I don't get when wp_nav_menu is not in the template and the post content is showing. The warnings are all "trying to get property of non-object" on different lines in wp-includes\post.php.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Shopp plugin. Apparently this is a known issue with Shopp: https://shopp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/47561/tickets/1905-shopp-products-in-theme-menu-causes-blank-pages

The workaround is to create a custom menu item instead of putting products into the menu.